# Do I need to create a new backup each time I generate a new address even with HD wallet on?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I don't really understand this. Back then I remember there was something about how if you generated more than 100 addresses, you needed to backup because reasons. I don't remember. I never generated more than 100 so I didn't bother.

Point being, there was some change on the format of the wallet.dat that supposedly avoids this problem. So I was testing the latest version of Bitcoin Core. And I created wallet1.

Here I generated some addresses. I copied this file and renamed it to wallet2. Then I generated new addresses. I reopened again wallet1, and the new addresses that I created on wallet2 aren't found on wallet1. My question is, how could I get the same addresses I generated in wallet2 to show up in wallet1 considering they share the same seed?

Do I need to create a new backup each time I create a new address? Didn't HD solve this?

In practice what's the point if I need to create new backups anyway?

This is always been so confusing to me. Because im paranoid im just going to keep making a backup of the wallet.dat file each time I generate a new address.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to backup the wallet every time you use the wallet to request a new receiving address.

It may be that your wallet, by default, only displays addresses that have a non-zero balance associated with them or which have actually been used as outputs in a transaction.

An HD wallet can be fully recreated from the HD seed (or seed-phrase where used). Exceptions are where you have also imported a private key or watch-only address. You won't recover supplementary information such as labels/notes you have attached to addresses, transactions etc, as these are not in the blockchain and therefore not recoverable from it. However you won't lose money. You may also need to set the derivation path if using different software and increase the gap limit if you have generated many addresses but not used them.